# What is an adjective to describe something that is aware of its surroundings?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I am looking for an adjective to describe an organization that does not only sense what is happening within itself (its own data) but is also aware of the (external) environment. One could say that this organization has senses/perceptors. Specifically, I am referring to an organization/ a group of people and *not* to individual organisms.

Words that came to my mind were sensitive (but the meaning is a bit different as it describes how you react to things you perceive), conscious (too passive), and sentient (like that one the most).

I would not limit the search to adjectives only if there are good phrases etc. to describe what I am looking for.

Comment: "Sentient" was the first word that occurred to me as well, but I think it has too many other connotations (awareness of feelings, intelligence) that might distract your audience.

Comment: “Sentient” indicates intelligence and awareness, but there is nothing in its ordinary meaning to particularly suggest that awareness is outwardly rather than inwardly focused.

Comment: If the context is a company, could you call them industry-aware?

Comment: This sounds like anthropomorphism — “non-human things displaying literal human traits and being capable of human behavior.” So any phrasings you might apply to humans would work. *The organization displays a certain sentience. It has its own consciousness. It is self aware. It is driven by its needs and responsive to its environment.* Do a search for *anthropomorphism of an organization* for more ideas. If any of this is helpful, I can expand it into an answer.

Comment: A less common word expressing sensitive but without implying relative strength is **sensate**.

Comment: @TinfoilHat I would appreciate an expanded answer. Sounds interesting!

Comment: Do you mean "organism" rather than "organization"? An organization is a human institution or establishment such as a company, governmental body or charity whereas an organism is a biological entity such as a plant or animal (an animal being any creature capable of independent movement).

Comment: @BoldBen As mentioned in the question, I am referring to "a group of people"

Comment: Something wrong with perceptive? Honestly asking

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***percipient***

capable of or characterized by perception [(Merriam-Webster)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/percipient)

Some examples of relevant usage:

*Incorporated the concept of observer equivalence that was implicit in the belief in a physical reality that is independent of any **percipient** entity.*
<sub>[Pfeffer and Nir, *Modern Physics: An Introductory Text* (2nd Edition), 2012](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Modern_Physics_An_Introductory_Text_2nd/meo7DQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22percipient+entity%22&pg=PA604&printsec=frontcover)</sub>

*When I perceive I must become **percipient** of something-there can be no such thing as perceiving and perceiving nothing.*
<sub>[Moeller, *Introduction to College Philosophy* (2013)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/INTRODUCTION_TO_COLLEGE_PHILOSOPHY/Td-fBQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=whether+it+is+percipient&pg=PA104&printsec=frontcover)</sub>

*The sensum, though distinct from the sensation, is dependent upon the perceiver. It is in fact a resultant of the meeting of a certain object and a certain **percipient** subject.*
<sub>[Ross, *Aristotle* (2005)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Aristotle/R_qHAgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=whether+it+is+percipient&pg=PA169&printsec=frontcover)</sub>

Comment: I have to consider this adjective as I haven't heard of it before. Thank you for the suggestion; will have to think about it.

Comment: A much more common adjective with the same root is **perceptive**.

Answer (score 2):

**outward-looking** defined by [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/outward-looking) as "looking beyond oneself; open-minded and reaching out to other people, organizations, etc".

We're talking about an organization or group of people, so any term is going to be somewhat metaphorical. Businesses aren't noted for the presence or absence of sense-organs or literal consciousness, but some are more aware of what is going on in the marketplace, with their customers, and beyond. It's this aspect of an organization that's identified by the term "outward-looking".

Answer (score 2):

**cognizant**

ˈkɒɡnɪzənt,ˈkɒnɪzənt, kɒɡˈnʌɪzənt/

*Frequency* (in current use):  5th level of 8

*Etymology*: apparently of modern introduction: not in Dictionaries of 18th cent.; not in Todd's Johnson 1818, nor in Webster 1828; in Craig 1847. Thus, probably formed anew, directly *cognizance n.*, *cognize v.*; but it corresponds in form to Old French *conisant*, *conusant* present participle Compare *cognoscent adj.*

1.
a. Having cognizance or knowledge (see cognizance n. 2); aware (of).

> 1820   R. Southey *Ode Portrait Bp. Heber* If the Saints in bliss Be
> cognizant of aught that passeth here.
>
> a1859   J. Austin *Lect. Jurispr.* (1879) I. xxv. 499   The party shall be presumed conusant of the law...his ignorance shall not exempt him.
>
> 1879   W. B. Carpenter *Princ. Mental Physiol.* (ed. 5) i. ii. §82   The following circumstance, of which the writer is personally cognizant.

b. *Philosophy*. That knows or cognizes.

> 1839   H. Hallam *Introd. Lit. Europe* III. iii. 162   Gassendi..gives
> as the best, a definition of truth little differing from Herbert's,
> the agreement of the cognizant intellect with the thing known.
>
> 1862  F. Hall tr. N. N. *Gore Rational Refut. Hindu Philos. Syst.* 54   If
> this cognition were that which apprehends objects, the soul would be
> cognizant.

Copied from the [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com)

Answer (score 0):

**attuned**

— aware of and attentive or responsive to something—used with to. [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/attuned)

— Receptive or aware. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/attuned)

— 1. able to perceive; sensitive (to) [Collins](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/attuned)

> The various information-processing capacities and
> information-gathering abilities that animals possess are **attuned** to
> the animals' environment by natural selection... *[Knowledge and Its
> Place in Nature](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Knowledge_and_Its_Place_in_Nature/7kcVDAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=attuned%20to%20species&pg=PA62&printsec=frontcover)* (2002) p.62

> The jungle is, therefore, not only a complex of many diverse and
> interdependent plants and animals, but also an intricate communication
> network to which the human mind can gradually become **attuned**. ...
> Your ears become **attuned** to this rhythm. ...The sense of touch also
> becomes **attuned** to the jungle.  *[Whistling Hunters](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Whistling_Hunters_The/9LjH0FOPBPIC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=attuned%20to%20species&pg=PA17&printsec=frontcover)* (1985)
> p.17

Comment: *Attunement* is more about degree than some basic ability. Training and conditioning can make you *attuned,* but you have to first possess the faculties that make you aware of your environment.

Comment: @GArthurBrown It can be, as in *finely attuned;* however the OP isn't quite satisfied  with *sentient*, and as you point out ("It doesn't even necessarily imply consciousness in the way we think of human consciousness."), it may not capture the *sensing/being aware of* part of the requirement.

Comment: That's a confusion of the meaning of consciousness and awareness. Ants are aware, but I'm not sure it makes sense to call them conscious. Likewise, you can be conscious but not able to sense your environment.

Comment: Looked up attuned and, unfortunately, it does not fit the intended purpose as also highlighted in the comments above. Still, thank you.